# Fresh Windows install from bootcamp goes to black screen (with cursor) after windows logo

Tags: windows, bootcamp, partition, startup, install

Bootcamp assistant successfully made new partition and then the Windows installation went through normally.
But when booting into windows, it shows the black screen with the blue windows logo and spinning dots, like normal, (which should lead to the login screen).
But when the blue logo and dots disappear, I just get a black screen with a mouse pointer that occasionally shows a loading cursor. Also, oddly, the cursor will jump back to the middle of the screen every several seconds.

I have tried:

- deleting the partition and starting from scratch (3 times)
- reinstalling windows on top of the one not working (twice)
- making a partition manually and installing windows (once)
- Letting windows diagnostics "Repair"
- re-downloading the windows 10 ISO and re-making the install media

At this point I am lost what to try next and its infuriating me.
Please, any help would be much appreciated!
Thanks

[image]

[image]

[image: This is the screen I get to that then disappears leaving a black with cursor]

Comment: We need a lot more info - what Mac, what OS, what Windows, what version BCA...

Comment: Hi thanks for replying, I posted pic of Mac,  OS and BCA. Windows ISO Win10_21H1_English_x64